# When I type @ in a input text it should show in different color in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
handlechangeMessage(event){
        this.setState({
            Message:event
        })
    }
    onselect(event){
        this.handlechangeMessage(event)
    
        this.setState({ showData: false
            })
    }
    onKeyPress(event){
        if(this.state.Message.charAt(this.state.Message.length-1) === "@"){
        if(event.key == '{'){
            this.setState({
                showData:true,
                
            })}
            
        }}

<div >
               <label htmlFor="edit-keyword-title" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                 Message</label> {/* Needs to get from Admin Configuration */}
                 <div style={{ display:"flex", flexDirection:"row"}}>
                   <input type="text" className="Description-message-container" maxLength="100"
                     value={this.state.Message}onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}  onChange={(event) => this.handlechangeMessage(event.target.value)}/>
                 </div>
                 
              </div>
              {this.state.showData &&
                        <div className="keywords-list" >
                            
                            {filteredData.map((row) => (
                                
                              <div  onClick={()=>this.onselect(this.state.Message.slice(0,this.state.Message.lastIndexOf("{")+1) + row.name)}>  
                            
                               <div className="inner-keywords"> {row.name}</div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                            
                            ))}
                            </div>
                            
                            }
```

I have attached the present output and desired output below 
When I enter @  in input text it has show some data and have to select from that data ,selected data should be in different color.

Present output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: You can't do that with an `<input>` or a `<textarea>`. Take a look into the `contenteditable` attribute, and get ready to lose your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

If its ok to use third party components, you can try [Antd's 'Mention Component'](https://ant.design/components/mention/) and give custom style for the color.